# PDO execute successfully, row count is 1 but fetchAll is empty

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a PDO select statement which executes successfully, `rowCount` is 1 but if I do `fetchAll` it returns []. Also `fetch` returns `false`.

Here's the code

```
$st = $this->prepareQuery(
      "select table.* from table where 
                type = 'OFFER' and 
                active = true and
                platform = ? and
                id not in (select users_table. table id from users_table where users_table.user_id = ?)");
      if($st->execute([$platform, $user["user_id"]])){
        echo "success";
        echo $st->rowCount(); // 1
        echo json_encode($st->errorInfo()); //["00000",null,null] 
        echo json_encode($st->errorCode()); //00000
        echo json_encode($st->fetchAll()); // []
        echo json_encode($st->fetch()); // false
      } else echo "failure";
      return $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NAMED);
```

This works on local machine (MacOS php 7.3) but on production server(php 5.x).

Comment: what's the value of `var_dump(st->fetchAll())`?

Comment: `var_dump(st->fetchAll())` -> array(0)

Comment: That's odd. Maybe some driver issue as `rowCount` is not reliable for select statement. Did you tried run the same query directly in your database?

Comment: Yes. It works perfectly fine in phpmyadmin, also works fine in locally.

Comment: I would say that during your numerous verifications you are fetching the only row and then all consequent fetches obviously return false. Either way it's a typo-like problem

Answer (score 1):

That is because some database drivers with PDO have no natural row count function [(rowCount() is only for INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE queries)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php), so you have to use another method. Here is what I use:

```
$sql = 'select * from table';
$data = $PDO->query($sql);
$rows = $data->fetchAll();
$num_rows = count($rows);
```

So, based on your `fetchAll()` there are no actual rows.

Comment: It would have made sense if rowCount was 0 but fetchAll() returned data. But here is the opposite situation

Comment: What do you mean @YourCommonSense - if there are problems with the driver it may be falsely reporting with `rowCount()`? There is no opposite situation, the driver is providing bad results where as counting the fetched arrays provides the correct results.

Comment: In the link provided by Jay Blanchard it says "For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement. Instead, use PDO::query()". In the link there is also an exemple how to do a "SELECT COUNT(*)"

Comment: @JayBlanchard same query works in phpmyadmin and returns one result. Also it works fine in XAMPP locally. So it makes sense that `rowCount()` returns one.

Comment: If `var_dump(st->fetchAll()) -> array(0) ` then there is no row returned. You're proving the point that `rowCount()` may not be accurate. What is actually returned from the query @quazar?

Comment: @JayBlanchard If I dump the query and paste it in phpmyadmin, it works. Also `select * from table` is behaving same way. I tried mysqli and it works fine with same query.

Comment: "*It works.*" How much data is returned? Share the results from phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Also, what is the actual query? Is the table really named 'table'? If so, `table` is a reserved word in MySQL and should not be used for a table name.